# test standard output with fish

Tags: shell-script, shell, fish

I have a script that prints a string to terminal,
and I want to check value of `myScript` output.(in this case `resultString`)

I tried with this method, but it didn't worked.

(for simplicty i replaced my script with `echo something` so the output is `'something'` in this cases.
)

```
echo something | 
    if test - = something
        echo true
    else
        echo false
    end
# this prints the false while it should be true!
```

also trying to set the output to a variable, but it didn't worked either.

```
echo something |
    set x -;
    if test $x = something
        echo true
    else
        echo false
    end
# this prints the false while it should be true!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` and `set` do not understand that `-` means "read from standard input". Use `read` instead:

```
echo something |
    read x
if test "$x" = something
    echo true
else
    echo false
end
```

Comment: Alternately, `set x (cat)` to capture all of stdin, not just the first line.

Comment: nice nice nice. thank you.`read x` works pretty good in my case. but `set x (cat)` no it works on bash tho.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but I don't think these command `set`, `if` can take input from stdin.

I looked up on https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6173

And it seems that the `test` in `fish` is a little odd. I could not work it out. However this works.

```
if /usr/bin/test (someCommand) = "hello"
   echo t
else
   echo f
end
```

in bash it is this

```
if test "$(someCommand)" = "hello"
then
  echo t
else
  echo f
fi
```

There must be a better answer. But this worked.